# jquery .load doesnt execute $ajax function

Tags: jquery

I wrote some code where one html file (file1.html) loads another html file (file2.html). file2.html (a form page) includes some small php code (calling session_start()), some form fields and some jquery javascript functions including a $.ajax() function which in turn calls a php file when inputs have been entered. When file1.html loads file2.html all jquery javascript functions of file2.html are executed well except the $.ajax() function. The $.ajax function does work correctly when I load file2.html (with $.ajax()) in the browser. Then I tried to solve the problem by moving the $.ajax function from file2.html to file1.html as indicated in the code below, but without success.

Where do I go wrong? (I checked at http://api.jquery.com/load/ and was looking at this site to get me in the right direction but couldn't find a similar issue.

Please your help.

Code file1.html (with $.ajax function moved from file2.html)

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").submit(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "step2_submit2ajx.php",
            data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(msg){
                $("#formResponse").removeClass('error');
                $("#formResponse").addClass(msg.statusgeneral);
                $("#formResponse").html(msg.statusgeneral);


            },
            error: function(){
                $("#formResponse").removeClass('success');
                $("#formResponse").addClass('error');
                $("#formResponse").html("There was an error submitting    
 the form. Please try again.");
            }
        });

        //make sure the form doesn't post
        return false;

    }); //.ajax

});

</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#section1").load("file2.html");


});
$('#page1').show();
$('#page2').hide();
</script>

<div id="page1">
page 1
<div id="section1">

</div>
<button onclick="toPage2();" type="button">< to Page 2</button>
</div>

<div id="page2" style="display:none;">
page 2
<div id="section2">

</div>
<button onclick="backPage1();" type="button">< Back to Page 1</button>
</div>


<script>
function toPage2() {  
    $('#page2').show();
    $('#page1').hide();
}

function backPage1() {  
$('#page2').hide();
$('#page1').show();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you not serializing your selectors :P

Comment: are you trying to bind to document ready after that event has already been fired?

Comment: @comment Benjamin G: thanks; I just replaced #myForm by #section1 in the displayed code but that doesnt work (unless you meant something different?)

Comment: @Matt: thnx, what code change would you suggest?

Comment: @MattWhipple if you bind a callback to document ready and the document is already ready, jQuery will simply execute your function immediately.

Comment: is myForm in the file that is being loaded?  You should use `on` rather than `submit` to bind, otherwise you shouldn't bind until the load success callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your submitted code, you have a syntax error.

```
$("#formResponse").html("There was an error submitting    
  the form. Please try again.");
```

Should be on one line or broken up like this:

```
$("#formResponse").html("There was an error submitting" +
" the form. Please try again.");
```

This prevents your submit event callback from binding. [Edit: Because the JavaScript engine can't run your included code block]

---

Since it's not a syntax error...  If you are loading `file2.html` which contains your form, but that bind to submit is in your `file1.html`, your form does not yet exist to be binded to.  Wait until `file2.html` is loaded before attempting to use `jQuery('#myForm').submit` either with a timed wait in file1 or just including the script tag with your .ajax handler in `file2.html`

---

Matt Whipple reminded me... you could also do it like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#section1").load("file2.html", function(){
    $("#myForm").submit(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "step2_submit2ajx.php",
            data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(msg){
                $("#formResponse").removeClass('error');
                $("#formResponse").addClass(msg.statusgeneral);
                $("#formResponse").html(msg.statusgeneral);


            },
            error: function(){
                $("#formResponse").removeClass('success');
                $("#formResponse").addClass('error');
                $("#formResponse").html("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again.");
            }
        });

        //make sure the form doesn't post
        return false;

    }); //.ajax
   }); //end anonymous success
});
</script>
```

Here you have your submit callback binded once the form is successfully loaded into the page.

Comment: thnx. However, I only made this syntax error when just submitting the code in the stackoverflow editor. The original line is not broken

Comment: Ah, I see.  I brought it up because it was the only thing I had to change in my test to get your code to work.  Have you checked your error console for anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: Oh, though there is a possible difference between my test and your actual setup, I include the script tag with the form in `file2.html` which I load.  Can I assume your have that script tag in `file1.html` and `file2.html` just contains the form?

Comment: my .ajax handler in (the original) file2.html is embedded within the $(document).ready(function() which has the script tag. Is that what you suggest?

Comment: Aye, that's how my setup is.  I put the script tag with the submit handler into `file2.html` after the form.

Comment: Actually, updated the answer as Matt Whipple reminded me that `load` has a success callback.  It's probably better to use that.

Comment: thnx; just moved the script in file2.html after the form, but still no success. Just reading about the callback function and wonder how to code that in the correct way?

Comment: It's similar to any other callback.  So on `file1.html` you have your `.load("file2.html", --insert function here--)` and the function there will run after `file2.html` has successfully loaded.  From there it should be simply rooting out any other logic or syntax errors.